# How to mock an hbase connection

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, hbase

I need to mock an HBase for the unit test. Particularly, my program will require a Connection to HBase. How should I do this? I simply used HbaseTestingUtility.getConnection(). But obviously, it doesn't work.
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe Hbase mini-cluster is what your'e looking for?

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this. I am using HbaseTestingUtility and used startMiniCluster method. I think I stared a mini cluster. But how can I get the connection to it?

Comment: `Connection connection = utility.getConnection()`

Comment: I tried this, but got a null return value. I also tried to first start up a mini cluster then getConnection(), but it doesn't work. Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got the connection established with the HBaseTestingUtil class (version 2.0.2):

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility

val utility = new HBaseTestingUtiliy
utility.startMiniCluster() // defaults to 1 master and 1 region server
val connection = utility.getConnection()
```

In case you need to add some specific configuration (e.g. security settings) you can add hbase-site.xml to your resources.